# How can Windows 10 boot directly to desktop?

Tags: boot, windows-10

`Problem:` How do I oust the following screen? Despite [the successful removal of my password (by following [this Tenforums.com post](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html)), I must still uselessly click 'Sign in', but LEAVE BLANK the password field (This proves the successful removal of my password), before I click 'Enter' to continue to the desktop .

`Details:` My Windows 10 had been booting directly to desktop perfectly (turning on the laptop had automatically ended with the desktop) before this problem started on 2016/4/4, on which date I downloaded the Windows app 'Scan' that forced me to enter my Outlook email and password.

[image]

Comment: You should try an auto-login program, such as that from [SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/autologon).

Comment: It appears you've more than one account. Hence the login page, I assume.

Comment: The exact same way you did it in Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1.  You set the default account.  [I can't seem to find my answer, that I wrote, so here is the tutorial its based on](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3539-sign-user-account-automatically-windows-10-startup.html)

Comment: @Ramhound that link is already mentioned by OP. OP didn't find a solution there.

Comment: @NVZ - Then the author did it wrong.  I have a Windows 10 virtual machine, I know for a fact, that information is 100% correct.